# Find day from String array based on iteration using Java

Tags: java, dayofweek

I have my string array and the input as follows

```
S = "Tue" and K = 23

        String[] daysOfWeek = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"};
```

I give my input as "Tue" and to find the next day after 10 days. I'm expecting answer as "Fri"

Here is my code

```
        String[] daysOfWeek = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"};
    int day = Arrays.asList(daysOfWeek).indexOf(S);
    int n = K % 7;
    if((day + n) > 6) {
        int index = (day + n) % 6;
        //return daysOfWeek[ ];

    } else {
        return daysOfWeek[day + n ];

    }
    return null;
```

Any ideas

Comment: Maybe you should post the code you tried.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, updated with the code

Comment: What is `K`?...

Comment: You need to use ``int index = (day + n) % 7;``

Comment: Does your code work? If not, in which way does it misbehave? What result do you get instead of `Fri`?

Comment: I used oleg code and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.time.DayOfWeek` instead of reinventing the wheel.

For example:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek1 = dayOfWeek.plus(10);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek1); // FRIDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

**Be simple!**

```
private static final String[] DAYS_OF_WEEK = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
private static final Map<String, Integer> MAP = Map.of(DAYS_OF_WEEK[0], 0, DAYS_OF_WEEK[1], 1,
        DAYS_OF_WEEK[2], 2, DAYS_OF_WEEK[3], 3, DAYS_OF_WEEK[4], 4, DAYS_OF_WEEK[5], 5, DAYS_OF_WEEK[6], 6);

public static String find(String dayOfWeek, int days) {
    return DAYS_OF_WEEK[(MAP.get(dayOfWeek) + days) % 7];    // NPE if not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do modulo 7 for the number of days after, and then you can find based on the output move the index to the result from the starting position.

Answer (score 0):

a mixed approach -

```
String[] daysOfWeek = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"};
int today = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getValue()-1;
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
    System.out.println(daysOfWeek[today] + " >>>     " + i + "  - " + daysOfWeek[(today+i)%7]);
}
```